# Creating a clone of databases on a new Microsoft SQLserver 2012 from Microsoft SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, clone, jobs

I have a Microsoft SQL server 2008 with name `'MSKUWWEBDB'` with 20 DB's and some jobs running. I want to clone all the DB's and the jobs to my new Microsoft SQL server 2012 named `'MSKUWWEBTEST'`. How do i do it?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [RedGate SQL Clone](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-clone/)

Comment: You won't be able to "clone" `msdb`, which contains the details of your jobs, as you can't restore a system database onto anther server unless it has the **exact** same version (that's build number as well). You'll need to script those out.

Comment: So you mean I need to create the DB's and tables again on the new server? Cant i Import the backups which i had taken of the old server? Will it not work?